# Searching for HTML elements in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, search, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

On this website, there's a `div` with the attribute `class="item"`. When I clicked <kbd>F12</kbd> to bring up the Developer Tools. I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and typed in `class="item"` and no results came back. I also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> but nothing returned. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Even if I search for `class=`, only text within HTML comments are found.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I searched for the XPath of the element instead and it worked:

`//*[@class="item"]`

Comment: XPath is hard. It is essentially a programming language. It is not suitable for routine needs like "this particular image fails to lazyload, I must find it by a string present in one of its attributes, but I don't know which one exactly because this is what I am yet to debug".

Answer (score 18):

Late answer but pretty sure `.item` would've worked.

Answer (score 8):

Search bar only supports string, CSS selectors or XPath selectors.

I recommend you use CSS selectors: `[class="item"]`

Answer (score 1):

Just use CSS selectors. Just `.item` would work here.

If you need some particular element with a specific class name, just do `div.item`.

Custom attributes work, too: `a[aria-label="Test Text"]`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it might be a bug. You can report it on http://crbug.com.

If you were to search for 'item' you should be able to find the elements that have the class item on them.

Answer (score 0):

Dayuloli's fix is a good one, you can also just search for `"item"` although that won't work if there are multiple classes on that element.