# How to see the single result of a HTML search within Google Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have reviewed a number of question on this such as [Searching for HTML elements in Chrome DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498176/searching-for-html-elements-in-chrome-devtools)
 and [How to search for only HTML elements using browser web dev tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51938800/how-to-search-for-only-html-elements-using-browser-web-dev-tools)

My issue is where there is a single result I cannot see it.  For example I performed a search of the id custom-header [image: image of web dev tools].  You can see 1 result and in this case you can see the result but it is not highlighted or coloured yellow.  This is a problem when searching a big website.

In fact when I search for something and there is multiple results i can see 2 to n results as web tool jumps to the point in the HTML where it is and highlights it in yellow, but the 1st result does not show up the same way.

Comment: It's a bug that was already fixed so the next update of Chrome will have the fix. Meanwhile you can add `|*` to the search text and press Enter (or the prev/next buttons).

Comment: Perfect and thank you.  I missed that one.